# Requisição Ajax em C# atualizar autenticação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

como eu faço para cada solicitação Ajax, dar update no cookie do forms authentication.

Quero dar update no no forms authentication no meu controller, pois ele é uma tela de agenda que usa o FullCalendar.

Estou tento problemas em uma página, que somente faz solicitações ajax e depois de um tempo se o usuário for para outra tela, pede login e senha.

Comment: Para as solicitações ajax, você está fazendo você mesmo ou está utilizando o `<asp:UpdatePanel>`?

Comment: Até aonde eu sei, fazer requisições Ajax não desloga o usuário.

Comment: Editei pergunta para ficar mais clara. É uma solicitação ajax normal sem user UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 1):

Dois anos atrás eu fazia requisições AJAX sem utilizar ferramentas ou API's de apoio.

O recurso alvo das requisições feitas via AJAX eram "Generic Handlers" (com extensão ASHX).

Depois de muito tempo só fazendo esse tipo de requisição, a `Session` dava timeout, e meu usuário acabava deslogado.

Eu corrigi, simplesmente acrescentando `System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState` à herança da classe.

Declaração da classe antes (dava timeout e deslogava):

```
public class DisponibilidadeHandler : IHttpHandler
```

Declaração da classe depois (passou a funcionar OK, sem timeout e sem deslogar):

```
public class DisponibilidadeHandler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
```